# Java - 'Finally' equivalent for if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

EDIT: I only want the `finally` code to be executed if one of the `if` or `else if` statements were true.

Many many times, I run into the following situation:

```
if (condition1)
    do stuff
    do something
else if (conditon2)
    do other stuff
    do something
else if (condition3)
    algorithm here
    do something
```

If there were a `finally` clause on if statements, I could reduce that into:

```
if (condition1)
    do stuff
else if (conditon2)
    do other stuff
else if (condition3)
    algorithm here
finally
    do something
```

I'm trying to find some solution where `do something` only needs to be called once, without making an additional method, doing some weird out of place if statement, or making a flag like:

```
boolean special = false;

if (condition1)
        do stuff
        special = true;
else if (conditon2)
        do other stuff
        special = true;
else if (condition3)
        algorithm here
        special = true;

    if (special)            // <--- bad solution, doesn't simplify anything
        do something
```

Comment: Can't you just put `doSomething` after the series of `if` and `else` blocks?

Comment: why not put `do something` after all ifs, it will executed only once, at last.

Comment: @Mritunjay because I don't think he wants to execute it if condition1, condition2, and condition3 are all false

Comment: @ajb, Well then let's not call it `finally`.

Comment: I'm not calling it `finally` because it's not legal Java.  I think the question is, how does he accomplish what he wants to accomplish without duplicating code.  If you change the logic so that it accomplishes something different, you haven't answered the question.  So maybe the OP shouldn't have called it `finally` but that's pretty much beside the point.

Comment: My goal is to have the `finally` code to execute **only** if any of the `if` or `else if` statements were true at any point.

Comment: It's Java, you're stuck with some verbosity unless you introduce a syntax extension.

Comment: if you write code out of  statement in the method it will be executed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java has a syntax that allows to achieve this without a flag variable, i.e.

```
doFinalAction: {
    if (condition1)
        do stuff
    else if (conditon2)
        do other stuff
    else if (condition3)
        algorithm here
    else
        break doFinalAction;
    do something
}
```

but you should think twice before using it. A lot of developers aren’t familiar with that and you’re not programming for you alone, most of the time. Some people think, it reminds them of the `goto` statement too much.

A cleaner approach is just putting “do something” into a method, e.g. `doSomething()` and call it explicitly:

```
if (condition1) {
    do stuff
    doSomething();
}
else if (conditon2) {
    do other stuff
    doSomething();
}
else if (condition3) {
    algorithm here
    doSomething();
}
```

The code duplication is acceptable if it’s just a single method invocation and the code even isn’t significantly bigger than the variant without.

By the way, sometimes developers go the route of being even more verbose, deliberately:

```
final boolean special;

if (condition1) {
    do stuff
    special = true;
}
else if (conditon2) {
    do other stuff
    special = true;
}
else if (condition3) {
    algorithm here
    special = true;
}
else special=false;

if (special)
    do something
```

Declaring `special` as a blank `final` variable has the clear advantage that the compiler verifies that there is exactly one assignment in every code path that can reach the `if(special) do something` statement, which ensures that no case can exhibit either behavior by accident, i.e. a forgotten assignment or the assignment being overwritten contradictionally later on. That’s especially important, when converting an `if … else if …` chain to a `switch` statement, where fall-through behavior is possible.

Comment: Instead of `break`, maybe just a return?

Comment: @Taylor: if the method consists of this code only, you can use `return`. Otherwise, there might be follow-up code that should not be skipped.

Comment: Encapsulation!  Makes the whole thing more succinct than using breaks, but this is subjective.

Comment: @Taylor: right, this is what the `doSomething()` suggestion is all about.

Answer (score 9):

Although there is no special construct to do what you want to do, you can rewrite the last attempt with a single assignment in the final `else` branch:

```
boolean doFinally = true;
if (condition1)
    do stuff
else if (conditon2)
    do other stuff
else if (condition3)
    algorithm here
else
    doFinally = false;

if (doFinally)
    do something
```

This does simplify your code, because the repetition of setting `special` to `true` is now gone.

Comment: You are correct but unfortunately this still falls under what I mean by 'having a variable as a flag'.

Comment: or even `doSomething(doFinally);` ?

Comment: Exactly what I was about to post. :D

Comment: @Hatefiend The main difference is that there's only one place for each action, without any duplication. While it's true that one needs to trace the logic of the flag in order to understand this solution, there is only two spots where the flag's value is decided (initialization and `else` branch) so it is much easier to trace, regardless of the number of other conditions in the chain of `if`s.

Comment: @ScaryWombat For some simpler code (imagine an assignment like `variable = -1;`), making a method for it is not ideal.

Comment: @Hatefiend if it was `variable = -1;` it would make more sense to do this `inline` rather than set a boolean and do it afterwards.  I am guessing that there is some code smell.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That is true and I do currently use this solution in my code but I was hoping there was some crazy way... maybe by assigning variables inside the `if` statements or something to get my desired result eloquently.

Answer (score 5):

Your third example:

```
boolean special = false;

if (condition1) {
    doStuff1();
    special = true;
} else if (conditon2) {
    doStuff2();
    special = true;
} else if (condition3) {
    algorithmHere();
    special = true;
}
if (special)  {
    doSomething();
}
```

is actually a pretty common idiom, and there's nothing "bad" about it, as long as you give `special` a descriptive name (in real life, that is; I don't expect a descriptive name here).  However, this may be best:

```
if (condition1) {
    doStuff1();
} else if (conditon2) {
    doStuff2();
} else if (condition3) {
    algorithmHere();
}
if (condition1 || condition2 || condition3)  {
    doSomething();
}
```

with the proviso that if the conditions are complex or could involve side effects, you should define `boolean` variables (with descriptive names) before the `if` to hold the values of the conditions, so that your last `if` is as simple as possible.  The choice between these two and your first example (repeating the doSomething() in every branch, which could be OK if it's very simple) is partly a matter of style, and I might pick different approaches in different situations depending on which one I thought was most appropriate in a particular case.

The idea of sharing code between different branches of `if` statements is something I've long thought would be useful, but I've never seen a language that actually does it (and if there were, the syntax would probably be difficult to understand anyway).  Just be glad that we no longer do the things programmers used to do when I first started, which would be to have two of the `if` branches use a `goto` to jump to the common code in the third branch.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (condition1)
    do stuff
else if (conditon2)
    do other stuff
else if (condition3)
    algorithm here
do something
```

or if you must have one of the conditions to activate

```
if(condition1||condition2||condition3)
    do something
```

Comment: yeah what's wrong with this one, this is what `finally` does.

Comment: When you answer a question on Stack Overflow, you are TEACHING someone how to do something.  If I took a programming class and the teacher taught us to write a series of if/else blocks without any curly braces, I would quit the class.  @Toxxic, I believe this is the second time you've posted an answer like this, missing the curly braces, in the past hour or so.

Comment: @DavidWallace OP didn't use curly braces, neither do I.

Comment: You're right.  All the more reason to teach him/her properly.

Comment: I have to agree, the lack of curly braces is neither grounds for a downvote nor relevant to the question.

Comment: @DavidWallace maybe you don't know this, but with one-liners, you don't need curly braces. Maybe I just taught you something without you realizing it.

Comment: And maybe you didn't.  So, you could improve your answer, and I'll remove my downvote.  Or you can argue about it and I won't.

Comment: @DavidWallace Not using curly braces for single statements is perfectly okay. It's not what *I* do, but a downvote for style preference... that's just not right.

Comment: @DavidWallace I think you are being unfair as this is the format that the OP used.  If you are going to downvote Toxxic, then you should also downvote dasblinkenlight

Comment: @Toxxic This solution would re-check conditions 1-3 which will cost time. Anything further using this approach will just become more verbose. This is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Hatefiend then dasblinkenlight's flag approach will work best for you.

Comment: @ScaryWombat dasblinkenlight's answer contains a good textual explanation, which makes it useful.  But if you don't provide text to go with your answer, then it's the usefulness of the code itself that has to be taken into account, right?  So the question is, is this code useful?  To me, all it seems to do is to teach bad practice, so I feel it isn't.  That's why I feel that dasblinkenlight's answer is useful and this one isn't.  But that is just my opinion - but then, all votes are the opinion of the voter, right?

Comment: @DavidWallace *good textual explanation* of your downvoting was very useful and as such I agree with you (not that I think you should give one toss). Have a good day.

Answer (score -2):

If this construction is the end of your method's body, you can use return

```
{
    ...
    if (condition1) {
        doStuff1();
    } else if (conditon2) {
        doStuff2();
    } else if (condition3) {
        algorithmHere();
    } else
        return;

    doCommonTask();
}
```

Comment: This does not follow the question. Only if one of the conditions were met, should doCommonTask() be executed